# End_of_file exception when creating TAR file with *ocaml_tar*

Tags: ocaml

When I try to create a TAR file using **ocaml_tar** library, I get an End_of_file exception.

My code ...

```
#require "tar";;
#require "tar.unix";;
let f = Unix.openfile "test.tar" [ Unix.O_RDWR; Unix.O_CREAT ] 0o600;;
Tar_unix.Archive.create ["write_ex.ml"] f;;
Unix.close f;;
```

... produces the following stacktrace:

```
$ utop write_ex.ml
Exception: End_of_file.
Raised at file "lib/tar.ml", line 549, characters 36-47
Called from file "lib/tar.ml", line 460, characters 4-11
Called from file "stream.ml", line 149, characters 33-38
Called from file "lib/tar.ml", line 578, characters 6-28
Called from file "toplevel/toploop.ml", line 180, characters 17-56
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: You probably want to [open an issue](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-tar/tree/master/lib).

Comment: it is already [opened](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-tar/issues/21)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It is actually a bug in the `Tar_unix` module. The `output` function wasn't robust enough and fails with `End_of_file` exception if the write was truncated. I've fixed the issue and your code works fine. See my [PR](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-tar/pull/20) for more information.

### Update

The PR is merged and the newer (0.5.1) version is released to opam. Upgrade to the latest version with:

```
opam update
opam upgrade
```

Make sure, that the latest (>= 0.5.1) version is installed, by querying opam

```
opam show tar-format
```

If it is still old, then force opam to install the latest one:

```
opam install 'tar-format>=0.5.1'
```